# How to change View in TornadoFx

Tags: user-interface, kotlin, tornadofx

I've build an application using TornadoFx. It displays a login window before loading the 'main' window.

My Question is how to display this main window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it's time to change views, call `replaceWith<MainWindow>()` to change the root of your scene to the root of the `MainWindow` view instead, optionally supplying one of the built in transition effects.

If you need to resize the window, override `onDock` in `MainView` and call `currentWindow?.sizeToScene()`.

An alternative approach would be to simply open a new window and closing the current window, using `openWindow<MainView>()` and then calling `close()`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but when I try to call `openWindow<MainView>()` the code doesn't compile and I get the error "No type arguments expected for fun openWindow(...". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SF23 or try `MainView().openWindow()`?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I found useful in this context is the `find(clazz::class)` function in TornadoFX which can get the node for a `View` that is currently being displayed by reference to its class name.  It works like this from most anywhere use the following command to change what is currently displayed from the `CameraLiveView` *View* to the `WelcomeScreen` *View*.  This helps not having to pass references across the application.

```
find(CameraLiveView::class).replaceWith(WelcomeScreen::class, sizeToScene = true, centerOnScreen = true)
```

Comment: This is better suited for changing views from within a controller. Since `replaceWith<MainWindow>()` is not available in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. It finally worked with `replaceWith(MainView::class)` and overriding `onDock()`.

Comment: Great, `replaceWith<MainView>()` is available in TornadoFX 1.7.12.